# Fragment recreated while using navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I have these 2 fragments on a single Activity. Fragment A with Firestore recycler view and Fragment B with the result from fragment A.

In my recycler view item click listener:

```
navController.navigate(R.id.action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB);
```

Now, when I navigate back from fragment B, fragment A is recreated.

Is there any workaround to save the state of my fragment A?

Comment: Your view must be recreated, Thats probably because it uses replace transaction. last i checked thats the way it is . So you have to save the State in ViewModel

Comment: @ADM thanks for the reply. Do you have a link reference for the implementation? Thank you so much

Comment: You can create a shared viewModel which is attached to the activity, and then fetch the details only once in the viewModel, then when the user returns to fragment A, they will see the results immediately.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encounters this problem, this is what I did.

Instead of using a regular fragment, I used DialogFragment instead to pop up only the fragment in full screen.

in your style

```
    <style name="FullScreenDialogStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
      <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
      <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    </style>
```

then set the style in your DialogFragment

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullScreenDialogStyle);
    }
```

[for Kotlin users kindly check this Gist](https://gist.github.com/utkukutlu/bd2e37253e7184179d923321e3ea72c1)